# just show every hour as time tick in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

i have the following plot from chart.js:

[image]

But right now I cannot find anything how to just show the full hour and going in 1h steps: So what I want is just a simple time axis scale with labels at 0,1,2,3,4,5,... so that multiple data points could are bewteen two time ticks like the data at 3:26, 3:58 and 3:12 are just 3 points between 3 and 4.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chart.JS time axis labels should be just in hours format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508783/chart-js-time-axis-labels-should-be-just-in-hours-format)

Comment: yes, Almost. ;-)